# How can I avoid NoSuchMethodError Create() using java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to convert a text file to Excel.......

while am doing that, the following exception occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.hasPOIFSHeader(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Z  
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create()
```

How can i avoid this?? I'm providing My snippet.

```
 public void convertCSV(String textfile) throws Exception {

            FileInputStream inputStr = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/directory/Desktop/HI/excel.xls"));

            Workbook HssfWork = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStr);

            Sheet sheet= HssfWork.getSheetAt(0);
            int rowNo = 0;
            int columnNo = 0;
                     Cell cell = null;

            // Loop through the files.
            //for(File file : csvFiles) {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(textfile);
                while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    // Gets the row and if it doesn't exist it will create it.

                    Row Row = sheet.getRow(rowNo);
                    if(Row == null)
                        Row = sheet.createRow(rowNo);

                    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
                    lineScanner.useDelimiter("\t");
                    // While there is more text to get it will loop.
                    while(lineScanner.hasNext()) {
                        // Gets the cell in that row and if it is null then it will be created.

                        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell tempCell =Row.getCell(columnNo,org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                        String output = lineScanner.next();
                        // Write the output to that cell.
                        tempCell.setCellValue(output);
                        columnNo++;
                    }
                    // Resets the column count for the new row.
                    columnNo = 0;
                    rowNo++;
                }

            // Writes the file and closes everything.
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(excelFile);
            HssfWork.write(out);
            inputStr.close();
            out.close();
        }
```

Comment: Im getting error at 2nd line 
        Workbook HssfWork = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStr);
How can i avoid that??

Comment: Give it the full path.

Comment: He does give the fileinputstream the full path.

Comment: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook interface .....I have used in pgm ...... Do i need to provide any other information

Comment: Have you tried it with another excel file? i run into the same problem, and it was because the worksheet contained 2 sheets with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

First guess would be: you've got the wrong version of a JAR. I'm guessing there are at least 2 JARS in your classpath, `WorkbookFactory` is in one, and `POIFSFileSystem` in a different one. Check the version of that second JAR.

`NoSuchMethodException` means what it says: the method that's been called (by `WorkbookFactory`) doesn't exist. So if you're getting it, it means the class `POIFSFileSystem` *does* exist - otherwise you'd have got the dreaded `NoClassDefFoundError`. So you must have the right library, but a different version of it where `hasPOIFSHeader()` has not yet been added... or has been removed...

Comment: Can u suggest me which version of jar files i have to use .......... for WorkbookFactory and  POIFSFileSystem for this pgm to execute??

Comment: @user2376026 use the latest version jar

Comment: I don't know which version of POI you're using, so how can I possibly tell you which version of its dependencies you need? Read the docs, or if that's too much work then first try the latest version of everything as per @anshulkatta comment

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16981013/685641), you're getting that exception because you don't have a matching set of POI jars in use. There are two common reasons for that. One is that you've somehow picked a mis-matched set of jars, eg `poi-ooxml-3.10-beta1-20130204.jar` and `poi-3.8-final.jar` - that won't work. Alternately, you have placed a matching set onto your classpath, but there were older jars already there, and your classloader has selected a random set.

Either way, I would suggest you following the [instructions in this Apache POI FAQ Entry on the topic](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006), to work out what POI Jars you're actually using. Then, work until you have a matching set. POI, in common with most applications, requires that all the Jars in use be from the *same* version as each other!